# GraphicsMagick mogrify to stdout

Tags: graphicsmagick

According to http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#files

> Specify input_file as - for standard input, output_file as - for standard output.

My attempt:

```
gm mogrify - < image.png
```

But nothing is printed to stdout. (Though I did happen to notice that the number of files in `/tmp` increased by one each time.)

Comment: `gm convert -resize 4000x filename.png -` should work, depending on whether convert, rather than mogrify, meets your needs.